# What is causing the error (index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, return

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    index = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            index += i
            break
    print(index)
    if 6 >= len(s) >= 2 and s[0:1].isalpha() and s.isupper() and index[0] != '0':
        return True
main()
```

Before I added and index[0] != '0' the code worked perfectly, but for some reason after adding that piece of code, when I go to input "KEVIN" an error(index out of range) pops up. How do I prevent this error from popping while still checking out the requirements for the code in the if statement?

Comment: It helps to trim code down to a minimal working example. I think you could delete the `main` function completely and instead have a canned call to `is_valid("KEVIN")`. Run that and post the output and error code.

Comment: Its odd to have a function that returns `True` or `None`. Perhaps have a `return False` at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

A smaller example shows the problem

```
def is_valid(s):
    index = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            index += i
            break
    print(index)
    if 6 >= len(s) >= 2 and s[0:1].isalpha() and s.isupper() and index[0] != '0':
        return True

is_valid("KEVIN")
```

`"KEVIN"` doesn't contain any digits, `i.isdigit()` is never `True` and the `index` list remains empty. Add a check for that case.

```
def is_valid(s):
    index = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            index += i
            break
    print(index)
    if (6 >= len(s) >= 2 and s[0:1].isalpha() and s.isupper() 
            and index and index[0] != '0'):
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not consider the edge case for when the string `s` has no digits. In that case, `index` will be an empty list and `index[0] != '0'` will throw an error. Consider adding a condition to check for the length of `s`.